# VBA Filter based on another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am VBA beginner and was trying to filter the data based a cell value,after googling around a bit I have written a code which works

```
Sub FilterDepartment_Sales()
    Sheet6.Activate
    Sheet6.Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Sheet8.Range("B3").Value
End Sub
```

I had to assign this macro to object to run , the data was not getting automatically refreshed wen I change the cell value in B3, how to make it auto refresh whenevr I change the value in the B3

Also in the above code when I try to do the following it gives me an wrror

```
Sub FilterDepartment_Sales()
    Sheet6.Activate
    'Sheet6.Cells.Select
    'Selection.AutoFilter
    'Selection.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Sheet8.Range("B3").Value

    Sheet6.Cells.Select.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Sheet8.Range("B3").Value
End Sub
```

I get an "Object not found error" , any reason on why I can't condense  the code like that

Base on the answer I had modified the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


    Sheet6.Activate
    Sheet6.Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Sheet8.Range("B3").Value




End Sub
```

But now when I change the value in B3 nothing is happening , do I need to add anything ?

Comment: Try taking out the `select` part.

Comment: *how to make it auto refresh whenevr I change the value in the B3* - Use the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run a code every time you change something in a sheet, you have to place the code within a method, which handles event of changing something.

[image: 1]

Here is the place, where you have to find change event, on the left you have to select `Sheet1`, then chose `Worksheet` fromd ropdown list, the right one will contain all events. Change event will be raised on every change, so you'll need to ,,filter" this and handle only situation when the particular cell was changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row = 2 And Target.Column = 3 Then
    Sheet6.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Sheet8.Range("B3").Value
End If
End Sub
```

In the example we watch for changes only in cell `B3`.

Comment: @ Michal Turzyn , can you please take a look at my edit