# Filter based on dynamic cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I filter columns of data, A12:I350, based on two cell values: B8 and L10.

The code works but I need to open the VBA module and run it every time I change the cell value. I would like the columns to auto filter once the cell value is changed.

The current code:

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub FilterBasedOnCellValueAnotherSheet()
Dim product1, product2 As Range
With Worksheets("Compensation Eval - Template")
Set product1 = .Range("B8")
Set product2 = .Range("L10")
End With
With Worksheets("Compensation Eval - Template")
With .Range("A12:I350")
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=product1, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=product2
End With
End With
End Sub
```

Following this question and answer: [VBA Filter based on another cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419664/vba-filter-based-on-another-cell)

I tried:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row = 2 And Target.Column = 3 Then
    Sub FilterBasedOnCellValueAnotherSheet()
    Dim product1, product2 As Range
    With Worksheets("Compensation Eval - Template")
    Set product1 = .Range("B8")
    Set product2 = .Range("L10")
    End With
    With Worksheets("Compensation Eval - Template")
    With .Range("A12:I350")
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=product1, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=product2
    End With
    End With
End If
End Sub
End Sub
```

The C2 cell value (Target.Row = 2 And Target.Column = 3) is changed using a formula that fills from another worksheet.

Due to the information from below I chose to make the field that starts the module upon change J4. This way a new value must be manually entered when the user wants to filter the data. I will also filter the data based on the field J4.

The working code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 4 And Target.Column = 10 Then
        Dim product1 As Range
        With Worksheets("Compensation Eval - Template")
            Set product1 = .Range("J4")
            With .Range("A12:I350")
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=product1
            End With
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

The issue was solved by moving the code from a module to the worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 2 And Target.Column = 3 Then
        Dim product1 as Range, product2 As Range
        With Worksheets("Compensation Eval - Template")
            Set product1 = .Range("B8")
            Set product2 = .Range("L10")
            With .Range("A12:I350")
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=product1, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=product2
            End With
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: Your comment "it does not seem to work" makes it a little tricky to diagnose, but in case you're not aware, this code needs to be pasted into the worksheet object in order to fire when a change is made to that worksheet.

Comment: This only works after opening the module and running. It also only seems to be filtering based on B8 once I modify the code. Could this have anything to do with the target row and column?

Comment: I haven't changed your filter criteria, so that's odd. If you've correctly pasted the code into the worksheet object (and not a normal module), the code will run every time a change is made to that worksheet object (i.e. the value of a cell changes).

Comment: To clarify, the code as it stands will run every time there is a change to the worksheet. If the change is made to cell C2 of the worksheet you paste the code into, the block of code inside the `If` statement will run. When it does, it will apply an autofilter to the worksheet (Compensation Eval - Template) on range A12:I350 and filter that range upon the second column - using the contents of B8 and L10 as its filter criteria. If that's not what you intended, add some more detail to your question.

Comment: Did you, instead, want the code to run if the contents of B8 or L10 are changed, not C2?

Comment: I have tried both changing cell C2 and nothing occurs. I also tried modifying the code to say: If Target.Address = B8  Then.... this way I could see if a simpler change triggered the module to run. However, the code does not run for either of these.

Comment: I just realized it may be due to the fact that C2 is auto filled upon other changes. Would that impact the trigger? So, I do not type into C2 instead a connected worksheet is changed which changed the C2 value.

Comment: Yes, if C2 is a formula, reacting to changes elsewhere, then `Worksheet_Change` will not fire. You could instead use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` to detect every time the active cell is moved. Or use `Worksheet_Calculate`. Both will run more than required so you might want to think about reducing it with criteria. Alternatively, you might want to consider moving the code to the worksheet that is actually being changed.

Comment: I see. I chose to move the filtering to be based on a hand input value in J4 and to Filter the information based on the value of J4. The code still works perfectly but it will not filter dynamically with the change of the cell. I will add more to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question is yes. You might have the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75802827/2685412) as posted. One thing I need to add is that it is a bit tricky to work on worksheet events. So I suggest you add an error handler and also turn the events off and on during execution to avoid other things like Excel hangging because of multiple firing of events. That said, try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo WeAreDoneFor
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo LetsTryAgain 
    
    If Target.Address = "$B$8" Or Target.Address = "$L$10" Then 
      With Me
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A12:I350").AutoFilter Field:=2, _
          Criteria1:=.Range("B8"), _
          Operator:=xlOr, _
          Criteria2:=.Range("L8")
      End With
    End If
 
LetsTryAgain:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

WeAreDoneFor:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsTryAgain

End Sub
```

You need to put this code in worksheet named `Compensation - Eval Template`. This is not tried and tested but I hope this helps.